# Database Design Has A relationship with Surrogate Key

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, surrogate-key

First I want to be able to update all attributes/fields and there is no single unique key. I have a hierarchy like each PC can be categorized as PC1/PC2/PC3 can't give example and each PC has Network and Software Info. Design and examples are

`Parent Table PC(EmpName, PCName, HostName,.... PhysicalLocation, PCType)` `EMPName,PCName,PCType` combined make this table unique.

Example record `('XYZ', 'Work Laptop','XYZ-PC',.....,'DESK-123','PC1')`

Child Table `PCNetwork(EmpName, PCName, HostName,IPAddr,....,PhysicalLocation,PCType)`

`example record1 ('XYZ', 'Work Laptop','XYZ-PC','0.0.0.0',....,'DESK-123','PC1')`

`example record2 ('XYZ', 'Work Laptop','XYZ-PC','0.0.0.1',....,'DESK-123','PC1')`

Since I want all fields to be modifiable, I have added Surrogate Key Id column to both. I have used PC-Id as FK to Network table but while inserting I would have to write a query to get the Id from PC table.

There are two problems, if I use natural/composite key I can't do update on every record since the updates are done through Asp.Net Gridview which doesn't allow primary key updates.

If I use Surrogate Key, there is a possibility of duplicate records and I can't refer them or put foreign key constraint to other fields since they can be unique only by combining all three fields.

I am using SQL Server 2008 and ASP.Net 4.0

I am missing something for sure, can anyone help or suggest a good design for this. Thanks!!

Comment: *if I use natural/composite key I can't do update on every record since the updates are done through Asp.Net Gridview which doesn't allow primary key updates.* Why do you think that?

Comment: Because I tried and I could not update the primary keys, it just updates the other fields but not the primary keys and some posts also said that Gridview update works with pk in where clause where as I am changing that pk and using that pk as condition.

Comment: Gridviews are only responsible for displaying and updating the *datasource objects* they are bound to. They don't update databases. Now its quite possible that your datasource doesn't retain old values making it impossible to handle updating a primary key but it's not the GridView's fault.

Comment: Yeah that's true the old values are not being handled, but I am not sure whose fault it is so I decided to use surrogate keys instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use Surrogate Key, there is a possibility of duplicate records and I can't refer them or put foreign key constraint to other fields since they can be unique only by combining all three fields.

You can have your surrogate key and still both eliminate the possibility of duplicates *and* create a referential constraint. Start by marking your candidate key columns as unique:

```
alter table PC
add constraint UK_PC_EMPName_PCName_PCType
unique (EMPName, PCName, PCType);
```

You can then add your foreign key like so:

```
alter table PCNetwork
add constraint FK_PC_PCNetwork
foreign key (EMPName, PCName, PCType)
references PC (EMPName, PCName, PCType);
```

I must say, however, that I don't totally understand your schema as described, so I'm not sure if there's a better way of modeling your data.  That said, here are some observations:

- `PhysicalLocation` and `PCType` seem like redundant data at first glance. You should decide which table they best fit.
- You could have a column in `PCNetwork` refer back to you surrogate key in `PC`, thus you wouldn't need `EmpName, PCName, HostName` in PCNetwork (but still create the unique key in `PC`).

Comment: What if I have null values in PCName(which I do have)? I forgot to add, since I have 3 PC types PC2 doesn't have(I mean it is not needed) PCName attribute so I hide it while inserting so it gets null but still the records are unique with that field being null as well. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: As long as your unique key isn't already violated in your data (including nulls) then this will work fine. All fields can be nullable in a unique key and any corresponding foreign key. You cannot create a primary key using any nullable columns, though.

Comment: I am getting this error `The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint FK_PC_PCNetwork  The conflict occurred in database "test.mdf" table "dbo.PC"`

Comment: If your unique key created just fine on `PC`, you likely have some data in `PCNetwork` that does not exist in `PC`.

Comment: Wow! I was thinking the same, thank you so much. Let me test by removing those extra data.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't know that I can make composite unique keys and use them as fk's as well. Learnt something new and it worked pretty well, I am able to update the fields and referencing also works. Thanks again!!

Comment: Hey I got a problem, I have two new columns to both tables and they are part of fk relationship and now the unique constraint works but not fk constraint like on insert it doesn't check if the data exists in PC table. On cascade delete, update also not working. I have added unique index thinking that I have more null fields but that didn't help either. Any help?

Comment: @scc I would suggest opening a new question with all of that info in your example. Also, the closer you get to a pure DB-design question, the better you might do on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: ya I thought of opening a new question but technically the same question since I just had two new fields and the constraints are also there but not working.

Comment: hey this is the new question [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40226/unique-constraint-with-multiple-null-columns)